# Transparent Mat-Accordion on Image

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a image on that i need a transparent mat-accordion with background black and text with white color. I want accordion to be transparent on the image.

I tried with below code:

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
          <div class = "promo" fxFlex="100%">
            <img [src]="inspectionDetailedImgUrl" width="100%" alt="Image" />
          </div>
          <div class="hilight" fxFlex.xs="100%">
            <mat-accordion>
              <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  <mat-panel-title>
                    Header
                  </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
               <h1>Welcome</h1>
              </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-accordion>
          </div>
  </div>
```

css code:

```
.promo {
    position: relative;
}
.promo img {
    z-index: 1;
}

.hilight {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    position: absolute;
    height: 85px;
    width: 415px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What? Can you word that a little more clearly, or provide a mockup? Additionally, made a transparent accordion, but I'm not sure this is what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-za3giu

Comment: I need  accordion should be transparent on a image not sure how to make custom css for accordion.

Comment: Did you look at my example? Only on the image? Is the image behind or inside the accordion? Can you mock it up? What you are asking is unclear